# Error While sending Base64 image to server while responce is an error

Tags: android, web-services

```
  public static String POST(String url) {
        String encodedImage ="";
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        if(filePath !=null){
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8;
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
         encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }else{
            encodedImage="";
        }
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("\"UserID\"", "\"9509\""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("\"MobNumber\"", 
                    "\"7030745576\""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("\"SelTest\"", 
                    "\"2\""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("\"EntTest\"", 
                    "\"2\""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("\"Prescription\"", "\""
                    + encodedImage + "\""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("\"AppDate\"", 
                    "\"2015-08-08 15:25\""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("\"AppAddr\"", 
                    "\"2\""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("\"RefDocID\"", "\"1\""));
            String finalString = nameValuePairs.toString();
            finalString = finalString.replace('=', ':');
            finalString = finalString.substring(1, finalString.length() - 1);
            String strToServer = "{" + finalString + "}";
            /*
             * String tempString = "\"objSP\"" + ":"; String strToServer =
             * tempString + finalString; String strToServer1 = "{" + strToServer
             * + "}";
             */
            System.out.println("strToServer: " + strToServer);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(strToServer);
        //  se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            se.setContentType("application/json");
        /*  se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));*/
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            // Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            // convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null) {
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                String jsonformattString = result.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
                System.out.println("Response : " + jsonformattString);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonformattString);
                    JSONObject resultObj = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("d");
                    finalResult = resultObj.getString("Result");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else
                finalResult = "Did not work!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.i("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return finalResult;
    }
    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;
        inputStream.close();
        return result;
    }
```

When i try to upload image i got error when response comes to server. but if i removed image data or send null then response comes what i wanted. i think error comes when i convert to json. but i m not shore. please anybody tell me what wrong with code . how to solved this prob.

Comment: `new BasicNameValuePair("\"SelTest\"", `. Why are you doint that? Normally you would ude `new BasicNameValuePair("SelTest", `.

Comment: `String finalString = nameValuePairs.toString();`. No that is not the way. Remove that. And use `UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);`.

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();`. In that block add `finalResult = "IOException: " + e.getMessage());`. Do the same for the other.

Comment: @greenapps thanx for your comment but i want same format . i mean in" "   its some business requirement . if you have some other option plz tell me

Comment: Please react to all the things i said.